# how to batch upgrade and build VC++ 6 project to VC++ 2010?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have thousands of VC++ 6 Projects, now i want to batch upgrade and build them to VC++ 2010.
I don't know how to do that.

**I will be mad if I have to upgrade and build them manually one by one!**

Any body can help me?

Comment: Considering VC++ 6 released in 1998, you will be lucky if you can even manually upgrade them to VS 2010, of course, one by one. Otherwise, a lot of code should be added to work with VS 2010.

Comment: No, I believe that there is some convenient way(dos command).

Comment: All due respect, believe whatever you want, but according to my experience, there is no convenient way to do that unless your code is magically independent of windows API.

Comment: I have found a related one. Could you modify it so that it can work for VC++ 2010? Here is the address: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6dsak0e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:
Upgrade VC++ 6.0 project to VC++ 2010

```
@echo off
for /r %i in (*.dsp;) do ( vcupgrade "%i" -overwrite -nologo )
pause
```

batch build VC++ 2010 project

```
@echo off
for /r %i in (*.vcxproj;*.vcproj;) do ( devenv "%i" /Rebuild )
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this, but this looks promising:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/25/to-the-command-line-enthusiasts-some-quick-know-hows-for-upgrading-to-vs-2010.aspx

Comment: This will upgrade the projects, but doesn't solve the problem that some of the code won't compile...

Comment: @BoPersson: How do you know it won't compile? He just wants to upgrade the projects.